# PHP Curl / Todoist / Adding Item

Tags: php, curl, todoist

I am trying to add an item with the todoist API using PHP Curl according to this:

> https://developer.todoist.com/?shell#add-an-item

It quotes this code:

```bash
$ curl https://todoist.com/API/v6/sync -X POST \
    -d token=0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567 \
    -d commands='[{"type": "item_add", "temp_id": "43f7ed23-a038-46b5-b2c9-4abda9097ffa", "uuid": "997d4b43-55f1-48a9-9e66-de5785dfd69b", "args": {"content": "Task1", "project_id": 128501470}}]'
```

I am trying this in PHP:

```php
$args = '{"content": "Task1", "project_id":'.$project_id.'}';
    $url = "https://todoist.com/API/v6/sync";
    $post_data = array (
        "token" => $token,
        "type" => "item_add",
        "args" => $args,
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

So I have the token, the args, the type but I can't seem to get it to work.

What would the PHP equivalent of that call be?

Comment: It looks like you've changed the data you're posting. From cli, you post `token` and `commands`, but from php you're posting `token`, `type`, and `args`. I'd guess you need to post the `commands` json rather and `type` and `args` from php.

Comment: The CLI is the example from the site, how would I go about posting that in a PHP Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = "https://todoist.com/API/v6/sync";
$post_data = [
    'token' => $token,
    'commands' => 
        '[{"type": "item_add", ' .
        '"temp_id": "43f7ed23-a038-46b5-b2c9-4abda9097ffa", ' .
        '"uuid": "997d4b43-55f1-48a9-9e66-de5785dfd69b", ' . 
        '"args": {"content": "Task1", "project_id":'.$project_id.'}}]'
];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure this is the equivalent curl command implemented in PHP. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Thankyou very much, I couldn't get it working at all but it seems to be working great!

Answer (score 3):

Compare the CLI example and your PHP:

### CLI

```bash
curl https://todoist.com/API/v6/sync -X POST \
  -d token=0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567 \
  -d commands='[{"type": "item_add", "temp_id": "43f7ed23-a038-46b5-b2c9-4abda9097ffa", "uuid": "997d4b43-55f1-48a9-9e66-de5785dfd69b", "args": {"content": "Task1", "project_id": 128501470}}]'
```

### PHP

```
// ...
$post_data = array (
    "token" => $token,
    "type" => "item_add",   //<-- NOT PRESENT IN CLI EXAMPLE
    "args" => $args,        //<-- NOT PRESENT IN CLI EXAMPLE
);
//...
```

The CLI `POST`s 2 pieces of data: `-d token=...` and `-d commands=...`. Howevere, your PHP posts `token`, `type` and `args`. Just make the PHP request like the cli request:

```
// ...
$post_data = array (
    "token" => $token,
    "commands" => '[{"type": "item_add", "temp_id": "43f7ed23-a038-46b5-b2c9-4abda9097ffa", "uuid": "997d4b43-55f1-48a9-9e66-de5785dfd69b", "args": {"content": "Task1", "project_id": '.$project_id.'}}]',
);
//...
```